# T-SQL Query only invoices between Start Date and End Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, ssms

I have a start date and end date range for fiscal year: 7/1/16 - 6/30/17

The date field included in my query is a pay on date that can be outside 6/30/17.

Example:

```
  Company  PayonDate
  Bose      9/30/17 <---Outside the 6/30/17 date range and will not show on report. This date will pay in advance.
```

I would like to show the last paid date in the date range:

Example:

```
 Company    PayonDate
 Bose       4/1/17 <----Actual paid on date vs. pay on date in the future within the date range.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

```
   SELECT 
   ven.VendorID,
   ven.Name AS [Vendor Name],
   inv.ReferenceNumber AS [Ref. No],
   inv.InvoiceNumber AS [Invoice No],
   inv.Payment AS Payment,
   SubMax.[Pay On Date]
   FROM inv
     INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT MAX(ips.PayOnDateTime) AS [Pay On Date], VendorID
        from inv
       LEFT JOIN ips ON ips.SourceID = inv.SourceID AND     ips.InvoiceID     = inv.InvoiceID
        Group by VendorID
       ) SubMax 
       on inv.VendorID = SubMax.VendorID 
    INNER JOIN ven ON inv.SourceID = ven.SourceID AND inv.VendorID = ven.VendorID
   LEFT JOIN ips ON ips.SourceID = inv.SourceID AND ips.InvoiceID = inv.InvoiceID
    WHERE FacilityID = 'HMC'
    AND SubMax.[Pay On Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND inv.ReferenceNumber LIKE '__-____'
    ORDER BY ven.Name, SubMax.[Pay On Date]
```

Comment: Something like `SELECT MAX(PayonDate) FROM Table WHERE PayonDate >= '2016-07-01' AND PayonDate < '2017-07-01'`

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I actually have that in my subquery.

Comment: What datatype is PayonDate? We can help here but we need some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: PayonDate is formatted YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00:000. Thanks for your help! I've also added my code to the question.

Comment: What do you mean formatted? I am asking what the datatype is? I have a feeling it is a varchar datatype. And what is the datatype of your variables? These things will make or break your code here.

Comment: Meanwhile you might check this out...https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @cmpmd2 while you do have it in your query; it's in the outer query.  wouldn't you want it in the inner query aliased as `submax`?  or do you want all records returned and only display the last pay date in the fiscal year?  in which case you should do a case on ips.payonDateTime but I think just limiting the inline view submax would work.

Comment: @Sean Lange - Sorry its a datetime datatype

Comment: @xQbert -  I'm not understanding

Comment: As far as I understand the relationships:
Vendor (ven) to Invoice (inv) = 1 : n.
Invoice (inv) to ??? (ips) = 1 : n.

Pay On Date is an attribute of ips.
You want only invoices, for which a pay on date exists in the filtered fiscal year. Is that all correct?

Comment: @cmpmd2  Does your PayOnDate have a time component, or are they all just 00:00:00.000? What version of SQL are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my earlier comment: (this would be too long to be a comment)

I'm assuming ips table contains multiple pay on dates per vendorID.
So could we just limit what dates we consider for the max to those in the desired range?

maybe I don't fully understand the question yet.

```
   SELECT ven.VendorID
        , ven.Name AS [Vendor Name]
        , inv.ReferenceNumber AS [Ref. No]
        , inv.InvoiceNumber AS [Invoice No]
        , inv.Payment AS Payment
        , SubMax.[Pay On Date]
   FROM inv
   INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ips.PayOnDateTime) AS [Pay On Date]
                    , VendorID
               FROM  inv
               LEFT JOIN ips 
                  ON ips.SourceID = inv.SourceID 
                 AND ips.InvoiceID = inv.InvoiceID
              -- Can we put it here? so that max can only be payondates in your fiscal year?
                 AND ips.PayOnDateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
               GROUP BY VendorID) SubMax 
      ON inv.VendorID = SubMax.VendorID 
   INNER JOIN ven 
      ON inv.SourceID = ven.SourceID 
     AND inv.VendorID = ven.VendorID
   LEFT JOIN ips 
      ON ips.SourceID = inv.SourceID 
     AND ips.InvoiceID = inv.InvoiceID
   WHERE FacilityID = 'HMC'
       --WHY HERE
       --AND SubMax.[Pay On Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate  
      AND inv.ReferenceNumber LIKE '__-____'
   ORDER BY ven.Name
          , SubMax.[Pay On Date]
```

Comment: This works! Basically I had the parameter dates in the incorrect place if thats my understanding of why the code wasn't working the way I want it too. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  you needed the date range limit to be applied before the max [pay on date] was determined.  so by ensuring max can only select a date within your fiscal date range then max can only be a date in that fiscal range.  The limits can't be on a WHERE clause as you have ips as a left join. thus the AND criteria on the join.  This way the derived table/Inline view called `SubMax` only will ever have pay on dates in the specified range.  I don't fully understand what you're doing here so **Test the crap out of this** before it goes to a production system! (sage advice for any answer really)

Comment: also note I think this is what @JacobH  was mentioning as his first comment; but they didn't go into the details to show you where to put it; which is what the underlying problem was.  Regarding the testing comment **make certain you test edge cases like a payonDatetime of `6/30/17 13:15`  BETWEEN use will exclude that record; when you may want it!**  this is an element Shawn was alluding to!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that date dimension tables are a god-send, especially when dealing with FY quarters that don't start on Jan 1. They add one extra table to join on, but they save a ton of processing and thinking. For a good date dim table, see Aaron Bertrand's example - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/. Customize with what you think you'll need; I've made several different versions that sometimes started with that as a base. But remember that the goal is to create it once and use it whenever you need it.

In your example above, build a date table that lists all dates for a huge range of dates, and include the fiscal year. Then simply JOIN the date table on the date where the FY is the year that you need to reference.

Window functions also come in handy. It may be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
          ven.VendorID
        , ven.Name AS [Vendor Name]
        , inv.ReferenceNumber AS [Ref. No]
        , inv.InvoiceNumber AS [Invoice No]
        , inv.Payment AS Payment
        , ips.PayOnDateTime AS [Pay On Date]
        , d.theFYYear
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inv.InvoiceNumber ORDER BY ips.payOnDateTime DESC) AS rn
    FROM ven
    INNER JOIN inv ON ven.vendorID = inv.vendorID
        AND inv.FacilityID = 'HMC'
        AND inv.ReferenceNumber LIKE '__-____'
    INNER JOIN ips ON ips.SourceID = inv.SourceID 
        AND ips.InvoiceID = inv.InvoiceID
        AND ips.PayOnDateTime >= @StartDate
        AND ips.PayOnDateTime <= @EndDate
    INNER JOIN ref_DateDimension d ON ips.PayOnDateTime = d.theDate
        AND d.theFYYear = 'FY2017' -- Or whatever FY you need current
    ) s1
WHERE s1.rn = 1
```

Comment: I created a script to create a date dimension that uses non-standard FY start dates. I need to blog it.

Comment: The date table has no sense if you keep the StartDate and EndDate parameters.
But I can confirm that a date table is very useful. Just an additional short explanation:
It should contain a row per date with as much attributes as needed (the date itself, day of week, month, year, day, week, fiscal year, date in different varchar formats that are often used by other databases/tables).

Comment: @RaphaelMüllner It makes sense when you JOIN it. The ips table will limit the dates to start and end date range and then only JOIN those dates with the FY year that you care about. That will make the row_number() you generate for it be the max date within your desired FY  Disclaimer Again: I hate dates..